# Отсутствуют элементы OleDB в панели элементов Visual Studio в проекте Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

Пытаюсь подключить базу данных к Visual Studio. После (ну в принципе и до) отсутствуют элементы OleDB слева в меню элементов. При чём в самой Visual Studio они установлены, но не хотят выбираться и перетаскиваться на область формы. При выборе "показать всё" в контекстном меню они появляются затемнёнными, то есть нельзя ими воспользоваться. В меню "выбрать элементы" выбрал всё, что начинается с OleDB. Как исправить?
[image: Наглядная демонстрация проблемы]

```
using System.Data.OleBD; //в начале проекта прописано
```

Comment: Студия последних версий? В ней не работает дизайнер источников данных. Потому что ранее всё было завязано на COM-объекты, а теперь всё кроссплатформенным должно быть... потому и не работает.

Comment: Либо руками в коде всё создавать. Либо можно сгенерировать код в проекте старого типа (там дизайнер должен работать), а потом скопипастить в новый проект.

Answer (score 0):

в инсталлере Visual Studio необходимо установить пакет для работы с базами данных. Полностью пакет нет необходимости качать. Покапавшись, среда разработки сказала что чего-то не хватает и предложила докачать необходимое.

Comment: `Покапавшись, среда разработки сказала` — ну, говорящая среда разработки, это ладно. но умеющая копаться!…

Comment: Я ЕГЭ уже сдал оцтаньте от меня((((((((((